# Debug instrumentation tests crash, normal run runs fine

Tags: android, cucumber, integration-testing, android-testing, instrumentation

I get:

```
Test run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':renetik-android-preset:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
```

I believe this is related to some update as this was working before fine. Now I cannot debug any instrumentation test.

I use Gradle 8.1 and it happens on plugin 7.4.2 and 8.0 too.